# AsyncHTTPTestCase dealing with xsrf_cookies

Tags: tornado

Is it possible to deal with `xsrf_cookies` from `AsyncHTTPTestCase`.

Currently if I write a test for a `POST` request as follows:

```
class TestFooHandler(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
        return application.Application()

    def test_foo_handler(self):
        body = urllib.parse.urlencode({'foo': 'spam'})
        response = self.fetch(self.get_url('/baz'), method='POST', body=body)
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
```

I get a `403` response code, even though the request returns a `200` response code in browser.

I guess it is because of absence of `xsrf` token. Is it possible to get past this  requirement for `xsrf` token during testing ?

I am on Tornado version: `4.2.1` with Python `3.4`, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `application.Application()` you must be passing `xsrf_cookies=True` to the `tornado.web.Application` constructor. The simplest solution is to simply add an argument to `application.Application()` to control that.

If you don't want to add an "off" switch for your security features, you'll have to supply a token. Fortunately, XSRF tokens don't need to have any particular structure; they just need to match between the cookie and the body. Wrap `AsyncHTTPTestCase.fetch` with a function like this:

```
def post(self, url, post_args):
    post_args = dict(post_args)
    post_args["_xsrf"] = "dummy"
    body = urllib.urlencode(post_args)
    headers = {"Cookie": "_xsrf=dummy"}
    return self.fetch(url, body=body, headers=headers)
```